# jQuery focus on textbox sets cursor when using alert but not without it

Tags: jquery, cursor, focus, set, alert

I have some weird problem when using focus() on a element.
I need to set the cursor at a clicked position. I can get the clicked position, but I am little bit confused, because I can not set it to this position in a focus() event.
Here my code:

```
function modify(value, item_ID, attr_NAME, obj_name) {
    var item_id = item_ID;
    var attr_name = attr_NAME;
    $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
    $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
    $(value).addClass('ajax');
    $(value).html(
            '<input id="editbox"' + ' type="text" value="' + $(value).text()
                    + '"/>');


    $('#editbox').focus(function(e) {
        var pos = GetCaretPosition(this);
        alert(pos);
    });


    $('#editbox').keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            $(document).attr('helpAttr', false);
            confirmAction(this.value, item_id, attr_name, obj_name);
        }
    });
    $('#editbox').blur(
            function() {
                if ($(document).attr('helpAttr')
                        || ($(document).attr('helpAttr') == undefined)) {
                    confirmAction(this.value, item_id, attr_name, obj_name);
                } else {
                    $(document).attr('helpAttr', true);
                }
            });
}

//Got this from the Internet
function GetCaretPosition(ctrl) {
    var CaretPos = 0; 
// IE Support
    if (document.selection) {
        ctrl.focus();
        var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
        Sel.moveStart('character', -ctrl.value.length);
        CaretPos = Sel.text.length;
    }
    // Firefox support
    else if (ctrl.selectionStart || ctrl.selectionStart == '0')
        CaretPos = ctrl.selectionStart;
    return (CaretPos);
}
```

Strange thing to me is that if I use alert(pos) the cursor will be placed at this position.
Is there any solution to remove alert, because it is disruptive to get a message box every time I click the textbox.
Thanks

Comment: This might help: https://gist.github.com/DrPheltRight/1007907

Comment: works but very bad. Sometimes I can set it sometime not. It works with some hanging I mean

Comment: if I place the cursor somewhere and ->if I only move out the textbox an release the mouse button, so there it works... but its not really what I wanted :-(